# Search with opkg

Tags: package-management, embedded, opkg

Trying to search with opkg command in my Onion Omega system:

```
opkg search vim 
opkg search v*
```

Got nothing in output in all cases. What I do wrong?

Comment: Do you want to search for a package to install?

Answer (score 1):

The `opkg search` command wrongly states it expects a regexp (regular expression). It actually expects a glob (shell wildcard pattern). Furthermore, the pattern must match the entire path, and it only searches the database of installed packages.

So on one of my QNAPs,

```
opkg search /opt/bin/find    # "findutils - 4.7.0-1"
opkg search find             # no match
opkg search '*/find'         # "findutils - 4.7.0-1"
```

But

```
opkg search '*/ls'           # no match, because coreutils-ls is not installed
```

If you want to find which package provides a file, there is no easy way to do this. You can search for package names,

```
opkg list | grep vi
opkg list | awk '$1 ~ /\<vi/'
```

or hunt through visually,

```
opkg list | sort | cut -c1-80 | less
```

Answer (score 0):

To search for available package use:

```
opkg list | grep package
```

or

```
opkg list *package*
```

`search` usage in `opkg`:

```
opkg search file
```

To list the package providing `file`.

`opkg` [manpages](http://wiki.openmoko.org/wiki/Opkg/Documentation):

```
   search <file|regexp>    List package providing <file>
```